# JavaScript not working as input field show/hide option not working in modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have one `select` field with two options.
Based on the selection of the option field it should show the other field which is a `textarea` field or hide that `textarea` element. This Form is inside Modal Popup.

I am trying it with the following code but it does not give any output.

```js
$('#remk').change(function() {
  selection = $(this).val();
  switch (selection) {
    case '4':
      $('#data1').show();
      break;
    default:
      $('#data1').hide();
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`<div class="modal" id="m<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);echo htmlentities($result->fy);?>">
        
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center bold"><b>Details of Letter</h4>
                
                </div>

              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="container-fluid" >
               <form  method="post" action="update.php">`
<div class="col-md-6 form-group" style="padding-right:0px;">
  <label for="Language">Remarks By CRDS</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="Status" id="remk" required="required">
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result-Status);?>"></option>
    <option value="2"> Accept </option>
    <option value="4"> Return to Originator </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" id="data1" style="padding-right:0px;display:none;">
  <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

I want to show the input field based on the value of another field It works fine but inside modal pop up it is not working

Comment: Are there other elements with the same ids?

Comment: @mykaf no all element have different id

Comment: You should remove the php from this snippet and include the rendered html instead. Are there any errors in the console? I think we need more context, since it only doesn't work inside the modal pop-up.

Comment: @mykaf What you mean ?Can u explain?   Is there any special method to call an element inside modal popup

Comment: It depends on where your modal is compared to the rest of your html and javascript. if it works by itself, something about the modal is "off." You didn't say if you had any JS errors....

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable is undefined
    bootstrap http://localhost/ioms/admin/assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js:22
    jQuery 11
    dataTable_fun http://localhost/ioms/admin/assets/js/custom.js:25
    <anonymous> http://localhost/ioms/admin/assets/js/custom.js:45
    jQuery

Comment: @mykaf I am new to this this is what i got in inspect element

Comment: I was also facing the issue .I also posted one question in that but it was unanswered.Problem me be with calling the ID

Comment: `$.fn.dataTable is undefined bootstrap`: search for this in SO or your favorite search engine.